# Creating a Continuous and Timely Process with Python Notebook and Tableau

Tags: dataframe, tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I'm seeking guidance on how to create a continuous and timely process in my organization. Currently, I have a Python notebook that extracts data from a database and performs various processing tasks on the extracted tables. The processed data is then exported to a tabular file.

Now, my goal is to establish an interface where the processed tables can be easily accessed as a source of data through Tableau. I want to ensure that the data displayed on the Tableau dashboard is up-to-date and reflects the latest processing results, based on a predefined timing.

Here are the key points:

Running a Python notebook: I have a Python notebook that extracts data from a database and performs necessary processing tasks on the extracted tables.

Exporting processed data: The processed tabular data is exported to a file, and I would like to utilize Tableau to visualize this data effectively.

Creating a Tableau interface: I need assistance in producing an interface that allows the processed tables to be viewed as a source of data through Tableau. The interface should provide up-to-date information based on the timing of the process.

Timely updates: It is crucial that the code runs at specific intervals, completes the processing tasks, and updates the Tableau dashboard with the most recent processed information.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this continuous and timely process. If you have experience with integrating Python notebooks, databases, and Tableau, your input would be particularly valuable.

Thank you in advance for your help!

any suggestions? which package / way to do it?

couldnt find a way to brodact direct DF to Tableau without create files such as CSV

Comment: Hi Segev! Welcome to StackOverflow. From what I gather, from what you're saying, you already have a Python [Jupyter?] notebook, which outputs data to a [csv?] file [on your computer?], and you would like to find a way of uploading this to Tableau, so it accessible to others, and have this done every x hours/days, and update some kind of viz which visualises the data. Am I missing anything? Can you clarify the questions for me? Thanks!

Comment: Hey
Thank you!
I've been using Python for a long time.
Currently, I process data (in a team), export to CSV and upload to Tableau.
I also process data directly from the database, but I would like a timed process - every week, for example, the code will run, and in a direct interface with Tableau, without the need to export a new, static CSV file, like I am directly connected in a live interface to the database, I want the Tableau to draw the processed tables directly from Python.
Is it possible? How?

Thank you

Comment: No worries! A friend of mine was thinking of doing something similar, with data on her employer's Hubspot. I assume you have some kind of cloud provider for the database?

Comment: There's two parts to this: getting it from the database to a computer with Python, and then from the computer with Python to Tableau

Comment: if the computer with Python is the database, then great! If not, that's okay too. If the database is a cloud thing with an API, I can help with that. Otherwise, you may have to sort that bit out on your own

Comment: NICE -the part of getting itfrom the computer with Python to Tableau - any reccomnedded package or API? look for a while, didnt find anything well

Comment: Just to be clear- I haven't used Tableau's API before. But, with that said, I've used many other ones, and based on the documentation, it appears very straightforward and painless. Here is a tutorial they wrote: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_get_started_tutorial_intro.htm and some sample python programs too! https://github.com/tableau/rest-api-samples/tree/master/python

Comment: There's information on uploading data to Tableau here: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_publish.htm . Happy to go through it with you if you want